# How to add/remove html element using jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I want is when add a element is clicked all the elements in div with `class="clLeft"` is copied in div with `class="clRow"`.

```
<div class="clRow" >
         <div class="clLeft">               
                <label >Question Type </label>
               <select name="selquetypen" class="clsvtext clsvtextempty" id="selquetype"> 
                    <option value="-">Question Type</option>
                    <option value="1">MCQ</option>   
                    <option value="2">True/False</option> 
               </select> 
              <a id="adddivcleft">add</a>                    
          </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: That's nice. [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: sir, i am new to jquery and javascript so could not tried. please help me out.

Comment: Here: http://api.jquery.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) it.

```
<div class="clRow" >
         <div class="clLeft">               
                <label >Question Type </label>
               <select name="selquetypen" class="clsvtext clsvtextempty" id="selquetype">
                    <option value="-">Question Type</option>
                    <option value="1">MCQ</option>   
                    <option value="2">True/False</option>
               </select>
          </div>
         <a id="adddivcleft">add</a>                    
 </div>
```

```
$('#adddivcleft').click(function(){
    var $elem = $('.clLeft:last');
    $elem.after($elem.clone())
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3n8pz/

Comment: thank you sir and 1 more query. if i want to remove added element.
can we insert html written by us instead of copying?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, this can be acheived with the `.clone()` method in the click handler:

```
$('#adddivcleft').on('click', function(){
   $('.clLeft:first').clone().appendTo('.clRow');
});
```

Comment: This is tricky; the amount of appended elements will increase exponentially because the selector includes cloned elements.

Comment: @pimvdb - yes, good point. Hadn't thought that one through...Edited to include ':first' selector so the cloning doesn't become exponential. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: thank you sir and 1 more query. if i want to remove added element. can we insert html written by us instead of copying?

Comment: If you have custom HTML, you can insert that with the 'appendTo' function. Otherwise you can add an 'id' or some set of classes to the copied HTML so that you can identify it for deletion.